# Migrating to Django 1.8 - makemigrations creates two new migration files in the contrib/auth/migrations/ folder

Tags: django, upgrade, django-south, django-migrations

I am migrating from Django 1.6.5 to Django 1.8.4 I was using South for migrations in 1.6.5 and I followed the instructions here for removing South and using Djangos inbuilt migrations
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south

I have a custom user model in accounts.models as:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Model extends auth.user and stores more information like city, about me, location etc

    """
```

I created a new virtualenv in my local machine (mac) and installed Django 1.8 and upgraded all the other required packages, and removed South. The tests ran fine. Interesting, when I did
`python manage.py makemigrations` it creates two new files in the `auth` app in Django's own folder : `.virtualenvs/dj18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/`

This migration works fine locally post that, however, when I commit these migration files (i.e. my own migration files *without the auth migrations*) into git, and deploy to my production server via fabric and do pip install Django==1.8.4 (full requirements.txt below), the installed Django folders do not have these two new files

```
 [X] 0007_customuser_extensionuser      
 [X] 0008_auto_20150831_2031
```

and hence my `python manage.py migrate` shows errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/showmigrations.py", line 36, in handle
    return self.show_list(connection, options['app_labels'])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/showmigrations.py", line 44, in show_list
    loader = MigrationLoader(connection, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 312, in build_graph
    _reraise_missing_dependency(migration, parent, e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 282, in _reraise_missing_dependency
    raise exc
django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration accounts.0002_auto_20150831_2048 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'auth', u'0008_auto_20150831_2031')
```

#### all the generated migration files

I printed out all the migrations from showmigrations after they were applied, so ignore the check boxes (X) to the left of these, just after doing makemigrations the checkboxes should be unchecked

```
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20150831_2048
activity
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20150831_2048
adapter
 [X] 0001_initial
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_customuser_extensionuser      ===>this is strangely created in the auth app, not in my own project's app. its code is below
 [X] 0008_auto_20150831_2031        ===>this is strangely created in the auth app, not in my own project's app. its code is below
authtoken
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
default
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_related_name
 [X] 0003_alter_email_max_length
django_extensions
 (no migrations)
djcelery
 (no migrations)
feeds
 [X] 0001_initial
friends
 [X] 0001_initial
globalprefs
 [X] 0001_initial
kombu_transport_django
 (no migrations)
notification
 [X] 0001_initial
push_notifications
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20150830_2246
rewards
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20150831_2048
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
sites
 [X] 0001_initial
survey
 [X] 0001_initial
taggit
 [X] 0001_initial
tags
 [X] 0001_initial
```

#### site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0007_customuser_extensionuser.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import django.utils.timezone
import django.contrib.auth.models
import django.core.validators


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0006_require_contenttypes_0002'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CustomUser',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(null=True, verbose_name='last login', blank=True)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255, verbose_name=b'email address')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('is_admin', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('date_of_birth', models.DateField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ExtensionUser',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(null=True, verbose_name='last login', blank=True)),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, max_length=30, validators=[django.core.validators.RegexValidator('^[\\w.@+-]+$', 'Enter a valid username. This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.', 'invalid')], help_text='Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', unique=True, verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='first name', blank=True)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='last name', blank=True)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, verbose_name='email address', blank=True)),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('date_of_birth', models.DateField()),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(to='auth.Group', blank=True)),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(to='auth.Permission', blank=True)),
            ],
            managers=[
                ('custom_objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

#### site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0008_auto_20150831_2031.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0007_customuser_extensionuser'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='CustomUser',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='extensionuser',
            name='groups',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='extensionuser',
            name='user_permissions',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='ExtensionUser',
        ),
    ]
```

#### requirements.txt for Django 1.8.4

```
Django==1.8.4
Pillow==2.8.1
Pygments==1.6
Unidecode==0.04.16
django-filter==0.11.0
djangorestframework==3.1.3
oauthlib==1.0.3
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.12
requests==2.7.0
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0
six==1.9.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
psycopg2==2.6.1
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
gunicorn==19.0
static==0.4
jsonpickle==0.7.2
django-celery==3.1.16
kombu==3.0.24
amqp==1.4.5
django-rest-swagger==0.3.3
django-push-notifications==1.2.1
django-uuidfield
boto==2.12.0
django-s3-storages-utils==0.1.0
django-storages==1.1.8
newrelic==2.52.0.40
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.2
xhtml2pdf==0.0.6
django-solo==1.1.0
jsonfield==1.0.0
numpy==1.9.0
django-tinymce==1.5.2
django-debug-toolbar==1.3.2
django-ckeditor-updated==4.4.4
django-stdimage==1.1.2
ipython==3.2.1
rq==0.4.6
django-mailchimp-v1.3==1.3.1
django-annoying==0.8.0
mixpanel-celery==0.8.0
memory-profiler==0.32
bpython==0.13.1
python-dateutil==2.4.2
django-extensions==1.4.8
django-report-builder==2.0.1
supervisor==3.1.3
raven==5.2.0
logentries==0.7
python-memcached==1.53
pylibmc==1.4.1
PyYAML==3.11
django-categories==1.3b8
nose==1.3.7
django-nose==1.4.1
django-queryset-csv==0.3.0
librabbitmq==1.6.1
mixpanel-py==3.2.0
django-cors-headers==1.0.0
responses==0.4.0
factory-boy==2.5.2
psutil==2.2.1
opbeat==3.0.4
django-log-request-id==1.0.0
billiard==3.3.0.20
freezegun==0.3.3
django-taggit==0.17.0
django-taggit-labels==0.3.0
django-taggit-serializer==0.1.1
django-qsstats-magic==0.7.2
django-import-export==0.2.8
Delorean==0.5.0
django-modelclone==0.5.2
dj-inmemorystorage==1.4.0
fake-factory==0.5.2
django-mptt==0.7.40
```

Comment: Well you need to run the same migrations commands on the server as well

Comment: Those migrations wont appear in the auth folder because they are not part of your repo (most likely) however, I don't think it is ok to have those migrations created, they break portability, as in your case.

Comment: Have you read the Django 1.8 docs on [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)? In particular, the two big yellow-box warnings about db structure and migrations. Seems there are a bunch of differences to be aware of from earlier Django custom user models.